# Windows 7 XP mode shutting down VMWare virtual machines

Tags: vmware-workstation, windows-7, windows

On my development workstation i use VMWare Server to run the different servers i develop against. I have run into an annoying problem because i have to use Visual Studio 6.0 and that wont run on Windows 7, but it will run i Windows XP Mode, so that's how i have installed it.

But when i start the XP Mode app. All VMWare images is powered off. I found [this article](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/232190;jsessionid=FE733F640D9C4C9E5BA63E77AF5E4332) explaining the problem. I now see why things happen, but is there anybody out there who have found a workaround? I know i could install Windows XP in a VMWare Virtual machine and run VS6 there, but it would be nice to know if there were a simple workaround.

Comment: Stupid Microsoft not playing well with others yet again. bah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way round with the current version of W7 sorry.

Answer (score 2):

If you're desperate, at the expense of your XP mode and VMWare VMs running slower, you should find that they can co-exist if you turn off Virtualization Technology (VT) in the BIOS.